# neo4j complex hieharchical Cypher query slow performance

Tags: heroku, neo4j, cypher

I have a complex hierarchical query which looks like this:

```
MATCH (comp:Company {id: 7})-[:HAS_SPACE]->(s:Space)-[:HAS_BOARD]->(b),
(col)<-[:HAS_COLUMN]-(b)-[:HAS_LANE]->(lane)
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)-[:HAS_CARD]->(card {archived: false}),
(cardCol:Column)-[:HAS_CARD]->(card {archived: false})<-[:HAS_CARD]-(cardLane:Lane)
WITH s, b, col, lane, { id: card.id, title: card.title, sort_order: card.sort_order, column_id: cardCol.id, lane_id: cardLane.id } as crd
WITH s, { id: b.id, title: b.title, left: b.left, top: b.top,
columns: collect(distinct {id: col.id, title: col.title, col_count: col.col_count, sort_order: col.sort_order}), 
lanes: collect(distinct {id: lane.id, title: lane.title, row_count: lane.row_count, sort_order: lane.sort_order}), 
cards: collect(distinct crd)} as brd 
RETURN {id: s.id, title: s.title, boards: collect(distinct brd)}
```

This query slows down to 10 sec when number of cards becomes about 200. What is the problem with it and also how can I profile it? Looks like there is a PROFILE keyword, but the output doesn't look like really informative. Btw, we are using GrapheneDB on heroku.

Comment: Do you have any indexes in place?   Looks like you should be indexing 'archived' and 'id'.  You might consider adding labels to some of those matches too - which might help speed.

Comment: Thanx. Yes, I have an index on id. Besides there is only one company, so index does not really matter in that case. As for archived there are only two options for this: true and false will index help in that case? "You might consider adding labels to some of those matches too " - what do you mean by that?

Comment: By adding labels, I mean that your query has a node (b) which isn't labeled; depending on the structure of your graph, indicating what label to match might speed that match by making the db consider fewer possible candidate nodes.  But most of your time spent here is probably in the collect(distinct()) bits

Comment: Well, all these nodes actuially have labes, but they are not used in query. Do you mean that using them explicitely with help? " But most of your time spent here is probably in the collect(distinct()) bits" - yes I also think, that might be the problem, but I need to use distinct or I'll have duplicates in collect. Still I can not understand how neo4j can be so slow on 200 nodes...

Comment: Perhaps you can share your database tump somewhere. And probably create a "profile match ..." output in the neo4j-shell to show how cypher runs this query.

Answer (score 1):

I think one issue you have with this query is the combinatorial explosion along the paths, you can help cypher a bit (the next version will be cleverer about it).

Also where is your "optional relationship" ? between board and card?

```
create index on :Company(id);

MATCH (comp:Company {id: 7})-[:HAS_SPACE]->(s:Space)-[:HAS_BOARD]->(b)
WITH distinct s, b
MATCH  (col)<-[:HAS_COLUMN]-(b)-[:HAS_LANE]->(lane)
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)-[:HAS_CARD]->(card {archived: false})
WITH distinct s, b, col, lane, b, card
MATCH (cardCol:Column)-[:HAS_CARD]->(card {archived: false})<-[:HAS_CARD]-(cardLane:Lane)

WITH s, b, col, lane, 
  { id: card.id, title: card.title, sort_order: card.sort_order, 
    column_id: cardCol.id, lane_id: cardLane.id } as crd

WITH s, 
  { id: b.id, title: b.title, left: b.left, top: b.top,
    columns: collect(distinct {id: col.id, title: col.title, 
                               col_count: col.col_count, sort_order: col.sort_order}), 
    lanes: collect(distinct {id: lane.id, title: lane.title, row_count: lane.row_count, 
                              sort_order: lane.sort_order}), 
    cards: collect(distinct crd)} as brd 

RETURN {id: s.id, title: s.title, boards: collect(distinct brd)}
```

It helps to analyse the different parts of the query separately and see where the combinatorial explosion kicks in. Then fix the cardinality of that piece back with distinct.

You can also try the new query planner by prefixing your query with `cypher 2.1.experimental`

Comment: Thank you, Michael, your version performes 10 times faster than initial query. Just curious are there any good guide how to write a complex query and avoid such pifalls? And also I tried cypher 2.1.experimental in web client - doesn't show any valuable info or I missed something.

Comment: This query is faster than initial one, but still degrades with slightly more amout of data. I guess that combinatorial explosion rises here: (cardCol:Column)-[:HAS_CARD]->(card {archived: false})<-[:HAS_CARD]-(cardLane:Lane), but really don't know the reason for this. So any ideas how to avoid this are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

After some research found out that this query runs 20 times faster if we "denormalize" nodes a little bit adding lane_id and column_id to card. Still it is not the fastest solution and I don't like this denormalization which eliminates relations. So I would appreciate any other solutions